# Passing character arrays by pointer in a function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

int scan_url(const char url[], char *hostname[], int maxhostlen) {
//stuff the function does...probably not relevant to this question
}
int main() {
    char url[63] = {'\0'};
    char hostname[63] = {'\0'};
    int help = scan_url(url, &hostname, 15);
    return(0);
}
```

I want to pass the char array "hostname" by pointer to the function scan_url. However when I try, I get the following error:

> error C2664: 'scan_url' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'char (*)[63]' to 'char *[]'

The error highlights the third to last line of code I have posted here...specifically it underlines the "&" in the function "scan_url".

What's going on here?

EDIT:

My purpose is to return the value of hostname computed in the scan_url function.

Comment: `<string>`? Is this C or C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because these are fundamentally different types.  Your function is expecting a pointer-to-pointer, but this is not the same as a pointer-to-array, which is what you're trying to provide.

If you want to write into the provided character array, then simply pass a normal pointer:

```
int scan_url(const char url[], char hostname[], int maxhostlen) {
    strcpy(hostname, "blah");  // or whatever
}


scan_url(url, hostname, 15);
```

Comment: The assignment I'm working specifically said that the value of "hostname" should returned. Is this accomplished in your code above?

Comment: @codedude: Yes, this will modify the contents of the `hostname` array in `main`.  Try it!

Comment: Hmmm. I used    int x;
  for (x=0; x<6; x++) {
   printf("%c", hostname[x]);
  }

Comment: But it didn't print anything. (I put it right after I call the function in main()

Comment: It prints just fine if it's inside the scan_url function

Comment: Hmmm. Well it's probably a small typo somewhere on my end. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can declare scan_url like this:

```
int scan_url(const char url[], char hostname[], int maxhostlen) {
```

And call it like this:

```
int help = scan_url(url, hostname, 15);
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually it's redundant to specify both a pointer and array notation as a function parameter, because they're both treated the same - as a pointer. Combining them means you're trying to pass an array of pointers, or rather a pointer to pointers.

To be consistent with the rest of your declarations just take out the `*`:

```
int scan_url(const char url[], char hostname[], int maxhostlen)
```

Answer (score 1):

Despite the confusing, overly-suggestive syntax, that `[]` in your function parameters does not mean an array, it means a pointer.

So, when `char url[]` appears as a function parameter, `url` has the type of a pointer to a char and not the type of an array of chars.

Similarly, when `char *hostname[]` appears as a function parameter, `hostname` has the type of a pointer to a pointer to a char and not the type of an array of pointers to a char.

In C, arrays are never passed in their entirety to functions, you can only pass pointers to things or pointers to arrays of things, but not arrays themselves. And that `[]` serves just as an alternative way for saying "it's a pointer" and the benefit of using `[]` instead of `*` is that you can show the intent of passing a pointer not to a single thing, but a pointer to a thing, followed by other things like it, IOW, a pointer to an element of an array.

OTOH, if you had `char something[][10]` as a function parameter, `something` would have the type of a pointer to an array of 10 chars. The first `[]` would "decay" to `*`.

If you had `char (*something)[10]` as a function parameter, `something` would have the type of a pointer to an array of 10 chars as well. There's no "decaying" of `[]` to `*` in here because `something` is already a pointer.

And that's pretty much what you're trying to shove into the function when passing `&hostname`, since, in `main()`, `hostname` is an array of 63 chars and `&hostname` is a pointer to an array of 63 chars.

But, as shown earlier, the actual type of the `hostname` parameter in the function is a pointer to a pointer to a char.

So, what you're passing and what the function expects are incompatible things, they have radically different types: a pointer to an array of 63 chars vs a pointer to a pointer to a char. And that's the reason for the compilation error you're seeing.

You should probably change `char *hostname[]` to `char hostname[]` or to `char *hostname`.